# Can't connect to host MySQL DB from Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I installed latest Docker CS, got a [LAMP container](https://hub.docker.com/r/fauria/lamp/) from Docker Hub. It runs MySQL (MariaDB) server and Apache server. I'm need it's MySQL server work with a DB located on host (or, alrenatively, create a DB on a separte docker value and use that, I guess).

The instructions say to start container as `docker run -d -p [HOST WWW PORT NUMBER]:80 -p [HOST DB PORT NUMBER]:3306 -v [HOST WWW DOCUMENT ROOT]:/var/www/html -v [HOST DB DOCUMENT ROOT]:/var/lib/mysql fauria/lamp`

I'm not sure what `[HOST DB DOCUMENT ROOT]` is -- is it host mysql DB location? Or it is any location on host where DB server from the container will write data to?

I ran it as `docker run --name mycontainer --rm -p 80:80 -e LOG_STDOUT=true -e LOG_STDERR=true -e LOG_LEVEL=debug -v /home/username/dev/appname/www:/var/www/html -v /home/username/dev/appname/wwwdb:/var/lib/mysql fauria/lamp`

The `/home/username/dev/appname/wwwdb` here is just an empty directory I created. I also tied `/var/lib/mysql/` which I got from `select @@datadir;` on my host MariaDB install. Same result.

I then connect to container: `docker exec -i -t mycontainer bash` and run `mysql -u root`.
and I get this error: 
**ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")**

I'm sure I'm not doing something right, but not sure what it is.

Comment: Hi @flamey, did you ever get a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.